# Obtaining a specific element of an output in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, output

I would like to obtain the number of likes from the output below:
[image: p]

Can someone please tell me how to obtain each element in the output and store them in a dataframe?
thank you.

Comment: try `print(media180['Number of likes'])`

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, it returns a "TypeError: 'Media' object is not subscriptable"